Unable to provision MAAS machine using Cluter API
Basically I have followed the readme and more specifically these steps
 1. kind create cluster --name=maas-cluster
 2. clusterctl init --infrastructure maas:v0.5.0
 3. clusterctl generate cluster t-cluster --infrastructure=maas:v0.5.0 --kubernetes-version v1.26.4 --control-plane-machine-count=1 --worker-machine-count=3 > my_cluster.yaml
 4. kubectl apply -f my_cluster.yaml


But all I'm getting is LoadBalancerFailed error (not sure why, new these this techstack)
LoadBalancerFailed error
Also after looking at pod's logs found out that it's a dns error (again not sure why, new these this stack) DNS error
